# React Native - Cannot read property 'DocumentDir' of null

Tags: react-native, rn-fetch-blob

Why my rn-fetch-blob package error?
"Cannot read property 'DocumentDir' of null"
I just want to convert my blob video to fetch a localURL
Anyone can help me plz!!

i try to rebuild or install react-native-blob-util still error.
but react-native-blob-util error is "Cannot read property 'getConstants' of null"

"react-native": "0.71.7",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have used the rn-fetch-blob plugin:

```
const { dirs } = RNFetchBlob.fs
const dirToSave = Platform.OS == 'ios' ? dirs.DocumentDir : dirs.DownloadDir
```

Check with the above way if it's working or not.

Comment: is not work for me
Also the error is showing in my app starting.

Comment: Thank you for your share, but i can done my work by other way.

Comment: Okay sure. May be you missed the initialization of RNFetchBlob due to which starting only error was coming.